Expectation of trend coefficient of ergodic diffusion process
I'm reading the book Statistical inference for ergodic diffusion processes(https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-3866-2) which is concerned with stochastic differential equations of the form
$$ dX_t = S(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dWt.$$
It assumes that $X_t$ is ergodic and therefore has as stationary measure $\mu$.
On page 158 it states that:
$$ \mathbb{E}[S(x)] = \int S(x)\mu(dx) =0.$$
It also states on page 159 that "it is easy to see that":
$$ \mathbb{E}[g(x)S(x)+ \frac{1}{2}g'(x)\sigma^2(x)] = 0$$
for a differentiable function $g$. This comes from considering the process $Y_t = G(X_t)$ and applying Ito's formula.
I'm struggling to find a proof of this (especially the second one). Any help is greatly appreciated.
Reference:
Kutoyants, Yury A., Statistical inference for ergodic diffusion processes., Springer Series in Statistics. London: Springer (ISBN 1-85233-759-1/hbk). xiii, 481 p. (2004). ZBL1038.62073.

Assume that $X_0$ has law $\mu$, so that by ergodicity, every $X_t$ also has law $\mu$. Then the SDE is equivalent to
$$X_t = X_0 + \int_0^tS(X_s)ds + \int_0^t \sigma(X_s)dW_s.$$
Take expectations. Assume that $S(X_s)$ is well-behaved enough that we can apply Fubini's theorem, and that $\sigma(X_s)$ is regular enough that the last term on the RHS is a martingale:
$$\mathbb E[X_t] = \mathbb E[X_0] + \int_0^t\mathbb E[S(X_s)]ds + 0.$$
Differentiate with repect to $t$. Note that the LHS is constant with respect to $t$ by ergodicity:
$$0 = 0 + \mathbb E[S(X_t)].$$
Finally $X_t$ has law $\mu$ so $E[S(X_t)] = \int S(x)\mu(dx)$, and the first question is complete.
Now take $Y_t = G(X_t)$ where $G\in C^2$. By Ito's lemma,
$$dY_t = G'(X_t)dX_t + \frac12 G''(X_t)d\langle X\rangle_t=G'(X_t)\left( S(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t \right) + \frac12 G''(X_t)\sigma(X_t)^2dt$$
which rearranges to
$$dY_t= \left( G'(X_t)S(X_t) + \frac12 G''(X_t) \sigma(X_t)^2\right)dt + G'(X_t)\sigma(X_t)dW_t.$$
Now do the same thing as in the first question, but this time on $G(X_t)$, to find that
$$\mathbb E\left[ G'(X_t)S(X_t) + \frac12 G''(X_t) \sigma(X_t)^2 \right] = 0.$$
Finally, let $g = G'$.

Thank you! This is basically what I had in mind; thank you for solving this so succinctly.
